# My Login Script

Tags: php, authentication

I am currently developing a login script for my application. The login will use SSL and all required resources will be served through this. It is not protecting anything like a bank however I would like to know what is right and wrong especially for learning purposes

I would love some feedback on my class that I have developed. I have been reading various sources on the net and a lot seems to be contradictory.

Areas I feel need improvement:

- Use something stronger than sha1 for storing passwords.
- Maintaining login - currently it times out after 20 minutes.

Without further ado here is the code:

```
class User extends Model{

    private $logLocation; 
    private $loginLog;


    public function __construct(){
        $this->logLocation = 'system/logs/';
        $this->loginLog = "logins";
    }

    /**
    *
    * Add User
    * @param    array   $data An array of data that will get added to User table.
    */
    public function add($data){
        $db = Database::getInstance();

        $salt =  substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)),0,3);

        $query = 'INSERT INTO user(  user_id, user_username, user_password, user_salt, user_forename, user_lastname, user_email, user_attempts)
            VALUES( :user_id, :user_username, sha1(:user_password), :user_salt, :user_forename, :user_lastname, :user_email, 0)';
        $args = array(
            ':user_id' => $data['user_id'],
            ':user_username' => $data['user_username'],
            ':user_password' => $data['user_password'].$salt,
            ':user_salt' => $salt,
            ':user_forename' => $data['user_forename'],
            ':user_lastname' => $data['user_lastname'],
            ':user_email' => $data['user_email']);
        $db->query($query, $args);

        SessionRegistry::instance()->addFeedback('user Saved Successfully');
        return true;
    }

    public function getUserId($username){
        $db = Database::getInstance();
        //Check to see if the username exists
        $query = "SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE user_username = :username LIMIT 1";
        $results = $db->query($query, array(':username' => $username));
        return $results[0]['user_id'];
    }

    public function getUsername($userId){
        $db = Database::getInstance();
        //Check to see if the username exists
        $query = "SELECT user_username FROM user WHERE user_username = :username LIMIT 1";
        $results = $db->query($query, array(':username' => $username));
        return $results[0]['user_username'];
    }

    /**
     * 
     * Checks login details against that in the database
     * @param string $username
     * @param string $password
     */
    public function checkLogin($username, $password){
        $db = Database::getInstance();
        //Check to see if the username exists
        $query = "SELECT user_salt, user_password, user_attempts FROM user WHERE user_username = :username LIMIT 1";
        $results = $db->query($query, array(':username' => $username));

        //No results return false
        if(count($results) < 1){
            $this->logLoginAttempt($username, 'Incorrect Username');
            return false;
        }

        //Check to see if the user is blocked
        if((int)$results[0]['user_attempts'] >= 3){
            $this->logLoginAttempt($username, 'Blocked User Login');
            return false;
        }

        //Check to see if the passwords match 
        if(sha1($password.$results[0]['user_salt']) == $results[0]['user_password']){
            $this->setLogin($username);
            return true;
        }
        else{
            //Incorrect Password
            $this->logLoginAttempt($username,  'Incorrect Password');
            $this->failedLoginIncrement($username);
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     * Increments the failed login attempt for a user. 
     * 3 Strikes and they get locked out.
     * @param string $username
     */
    private function failedLoginIncrement($username){
        $db = Database::getInstance();          
        //Update the IP address of the user from where they last logged in
        $query = 'UPDATE user SET user_attempts = user_attempts + 1 WHERE user_username = :username';
        $db->query($query, array(':username' => $username));

        //Check to see if the user has reached 3 strikes if so block them.
        $query = 'SELECT user_attempts FROM user WHERE user_username = :username LIMIT 1';
        $results = $db->query($query, array(':username' => $username));

        if($results[0]['user_attempts'] >= 3){
            //We need to block the user
            $query = 'UPDATE user SET user_blocked = 1 WHERE user_username = :username';
            $db->query($query, array(':username' => $username));
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * Logs a failed login attempt to a log file so these can be monitored
     * @param string $username 
     * @param string $reason
     */
    private function logLoginAttempt($username, $reason){
        $fh = fopen($this->logLocation.$this->loginLog, 'a+') or die("can't open file");
        $logLine = date('d/m/Y h:i') . ' Login Attempt: ' . $username . ' Failure Reason: ' . $reason . " IP: " . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "\n";
        fwrite($fh, $logLine);
        fclose($fh);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * Sets the login data in the session. Also logs IP and resets the failed attempts.
     * @param string $username
     */
    private function setLogin($username){           
        $db = Database::getInstance();          
        //Update the IP address of the user from where they last logged in
        $query = 'UPDATE user SET user_ip = :ip, user_attempts = 0 WHERE user_username = :username';
        $db->query($query, array(':username' => $username, ':ip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));

        ini_set("session.use_only_cookies", TRUE);  //Forces the session to be stored only in cookies and not passed over a URI.
        ini_set("session.use_trans_sid", FALSE);    //Stop leaking session IDs onto the URI before browser can check to see if cookies are enabled.
        ini_set("session.cookie_lifetime", 1200);    //Time out after 20mins

        //Now add the session vars to set the user to logged in.
        session_start();
        session_regenerate_id(true); //Regenerate the session Id deleting old session files.
        $_SESSION['valid'] = 1;
        $_SESSION['userid'] = sha1($this->getUserId($_POST['username'] . "SALTHERE"));
    }

    /**
     * 
     * Checks to see if a user is currently logged in.
     */
    public function loggedIn(){
        if($_SESSION['valid']){
            return true;
        }   
        else{
            return false;
        }       
    }   

    /**
     * 
     * Logs a current user out by destroying the session
     */
    public function logout(){
        // Unset all of the session variables.
        $_SESSION = array();

        // If it's desired to kill the session, also delete the session cookie.
        // Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!
        if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
            $params = session_get_cookie_params();
            setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
                $params["path"], $params["domain"],
                $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
            );
        }           
        // Finally, destroy the session.
        session_destroy();
    }
}
```

I then use this class like so:

```
require_once('User.php');
$user = new User();
$loggedIn = $user->checkLogin($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);
if($loggedIn){
  //redirect to member area
}
else{
  //show login screen
}
```

Then on a page where I need to check if a user is logged in

```
require_once('User.php');
$user = new User();
if(!$user->loggedIn()){
  //redirect to login page
}
```

I would love to hear your thoughts comments good or bad plus any other ideas I can use to improve my login script.

Thanks in advance for your time

Matt

Comment: You might get more help posting this here instead: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: It helps to have more specific questions; something like "this doesn't work in case a" or "i've heard conflicting opinions a and b, which is right?"

Answer (score 0):

I suggest separating the session management from the database access.  Put them somehow into two different classes.

Comment: Thanks Dave that does make sense now that you mention it. I guess I was trying to get the basics nailed down first in principle.